# Should one service access the data of another service directly?

Tags: web-services, architecture, microservices

I am implementing a small-scale web backend system for a small company using microservices, but with each service sharing a central DB.

Lets say I have an Orders service, and an Invoice service. If my Invoice service has to read (not modify) some data involving Orders, should it access the Orders DB data directly, or should it make an HTTP request to the Orders service (which in turn accesses the DB) ?

Which would be a better design architecture-wise?

Here are my thoughts:

If it makes an HTTP request, each service is more isolated since it does not touch the data 'owned' by another service.

If it directly reads the data from the DB, it is more independent and can be deployed independently. If the Orders service fails, the Invoice service can still run and be functional (at least for the parts that depend on that Orders data).

The operation is read-only. Curious to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Microservices in general need to own their own data, so they should have exclusive use (in terms of queries and writes) of the DBs they use.

Directly reading from the DB doesn't make them independently deployable: at actually makes their deployment depend on each other, because changes to how one service wants to use the data will tend to require that the other be changed and redeployed.

It is true that a request/response interaction between the services implies a temporal coupling (that they both must be running at the same time).  You can remove that coupling and make the two services actually be independent by having changes in the Orders service be published to the Invoice service and have the Invoice service maintain its view of the Order information in the Invoice service's database.  Change data capture in the database can be very useful for this.